# Ring morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How would I find all the ring morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$? I know that if the map function is $f(x)$, we must have that $f(1) = 1$ and that $f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$, as well as $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$.

In other such questions, I understand that if it's from say $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ then it's much easier since 15's a multiple of 3.

However, I'm not sure how to find the morphisms if their relatively prime numbers.

Comment: Forget rings and just think about the additive abelian groups.

Comment: I think it's *much* easier to count morphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ when $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime!

Comment: What are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_7$? Those are the candidates for the kernel.

Comment: There is at most one map $f: \mathbb{Z}/m \to \mathbb{Z}/n$ such that $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 6):

Considering *ring* homomorphisms adds unnecessary complications. Let's start looking at homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_m\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n$ of the additive groups.

We know that

- $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ must be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$;
- every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_N$ has a number of elements dividing $N$;
- by the isomorphism theorem $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ must have a number of elements dividing $m$.

Putting all these things together the number of elements in $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ must divide **both** $m$ and $n$.

Hence, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime the only possibility is that $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ has only one element, which must be $0$ and $\phi=0$ identically.

Now observe that a ring homomorphism must be a homomorphism of the additive groups.

Comment: Nice. It looks like all that is necessary is the cardinalities of the groups be relatively prime—you didn't even use the fact that the domain and codomain are cyclic.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: you are right. In fact my entire post remains valid verbatim for a group homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ between any two finite groups of coprime order.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_7 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ be a homomorphism. Then
$$
    f(4) = f(1+1+1+1) = f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) = 0
$$
But then
$$
    f(1) = f(4+4) = f(4) + f(4) = 0
$$
So $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_7$.

In general, suppose that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and consider $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$. Then $f(n) = n \cdot f(1) = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. There exists an integer $a$ such that $a n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. But then also, $f(1) = f(an) = a f(n) = 0$. So $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_m$.